# Reading names from a file, put in list — how can I update the list without restarting script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables, append

I need some help with Python (3).

*users.txt* is a list of usernames that are fetched from a website, each on a separate line. In my code, the first block reads *users.txt*, adding it to the `users` variable with the newlines removed, as a list.

The `write_to_users_add()` function appends what’s in `users` to *users.txt*.

The last part is used later in the code to append new users to `users`and append them to the *users.txt* file.

---

My problem is that when a new user is added to `users` and *users.txt*, the first block doesn’t re-read *users.txt* and add any new usernames to the `users` variable. It also duplicates the entire text file because the variable already has the names in it.

I’ve tried using an async function, but I couldn’t figure out how to achieve it as I’m not that familiar with asynchronous functions in Python. I also tried a few different things, such as making the first block a function and calling it in the last code block; as well as just two variables—`users` and `users_add`, and that solves the duplication issue but not the other issue of the variable not recognizing new names.

**TL;DR:** Script reads *users.txt*, adds names to `users` var. I later append new names to `users` and then to the txt file. How can I keep the `users` var updated with new users without restarting the script and without the names in *users.txt* duplicating? If anybody here could offer me some help with this problem, I would be very grateful!

```py
# 1. Read users.txt
if os.path.isfile('users.txt'):
    with open('users.txt', 'r') as \
            file:
        users = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]

# 2. Function for writing to users.txt
def write_to_users():
    try:
        with open('users.txt', 'a') \
                as file:
            for item in users:
                file.write('{}\n'.format(item))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Current path:', os.getcwd())
        print('Isdir reports:', os.path.isdir(os.getcwd()))
        print('Isfile reports:', os.path.isfile(
            'users.txt'))
        raise
```

---

```py
users.append(author)
write_to_users()
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Why are you reading the file twice? Your loop at the end does the same thing as the code at the beginning, but reads into `uses` instead of `users_add`. And for some reason, you delete everything in `users_add` first with `users_add = []`

Comment: One issue, at the end you do `user_add = []` and then fill in a `users` list. But `write_to_users_add` uses the new empty `user_add`.

Comment: @Barmar @tdelaney I’ve edited my post with the third block removed, but as I mentioned, this imposes a separate issue where the _users.txt_ file has its contents duplicated when a new name is added to it, probably because the `users` var already has the names. My goal is to be able to read the names from the file and use them in a list var; and then later add new names to the file whilst also having the var refresh without a script restart. I’m not quite amazing at Python just yet, but I’ve tried everything I can, and I can’t figure this out.

Comment: If you're appending to the file, you should be working with a different list than the one you originally read from the file. Or you should save the length of the original list, and then only write the new elements after that index. Otherwise, you're duplicating what's already in the file.